# how to use formula to compare value in array

Tags: excel, formula, lookup

I wanna set a formula in using lookup to get the different (latest VS last) base on same vendor & style but fail....

for example: coco, gk, 8-Jun VS coco, gk, 2-Jun
cell E3 value = -86

can anyone help? thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSABV.png)

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You need a few formulas for this.

Every formula is an Array formula so you must use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when leaving the formula bar.

You fist need to find the value last entry for yor vendor and style but before you get the value, you need to get the row of the last entry

`=MAX(IF((A:A=A2)*(C:C=C2),ROW(A:A)-ROW(INDEX(A:A,1,1))+1))`

will the return the row number where the vendor and style match the data in A2 and C2.

From the row you can return the value using `index`

```
`index(D:D,MAX(IF((A:A=A2)*(C:C=C2),ROW(A:A)-ROW(INDEX(A:A,1,1))+1)),1)`
```

The item row matching the criteria with the maximum date can be found using

`=IFERROR(MATCH(1,(A2=A:A)*(MAX(IF(A:A=A2,B:B))=B:B)*(C2=C:C),0),ROW())`

The value by using index

`index(D:D,IFERROR(MATCH(1,(A2=A:A)*(MAX(IF(A:A=A2,B:B))=B:B)*(C2=C:C),0),ROW()),1)`

Put them together to do the calculation

```
=index(D:D,MAX(IF((A:A=A2)*(C:C=C2),ROW(A:A)-ROW(INDEX(A:A,1,1))+1)),1)-index(D:D,IFERROR(MATCH(1,(A2=A:A)*(MAX(IF(A:A=A2,B:B))=B:B)*(C2=C:C),0),ROW()),1)
```